# Piwik : Should be redirected to report page after clicking on URL

Tags: php, matomo

I am fetching the data from database. If i click the url(as present in image) it goes to particular website page. But i wanted to redirect the particular report page when i click the particular url.

```
<?php
 public function getTemperatures()
{
    $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user     = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "api_enterprise";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Oops some thing went wrong");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Oops some thing went wrong");// we are now connected to database

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM website"); // selecting data through mysql_query()


while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 $temperatures[] = array(

 'label1' => '<a href="'.$data['link'].'" target="_blank">'.$data['link'].'</a>',
 'label2' => $data['time'],
 'label3' => $data['os'],
 'label4' => $data['browser'],
 'label5' => $data['status'],
 'label6' => $data['location'],
 array('label6' => $data['widget_load_time'])
 );

}    
return DataTable::makeFromIndexedArray($temperatures);
}
```

[image: list of url]

Comment: mysql is deprecated, Try mysqli or better yet PDO, Also you lost me at particular, Try providing a bit more information because it is hard to understand what you need.

Comment: If i click the url it goes to website page. But i wanted to redirect my custom report page. @JoshuaNightingale

Answer (score 0):

I looked at piwik demo. I thing this is what your need:

```
'label1' => '<a href="index.php?module=CoreHome&action=index&date=yesterday&period=day&idSite='.$data['id'].'" target="_blank">'.$data['link'].'</a>',
```

You can edit period and date params as you need. But maybe is a bether way to generate this link.